# Windows 10 error (page fault in nonpaged area ) failed:volsnap

Tags: windows, windows-10

I was using my pc normally and its running latest version of windows 10 developer build, when the power went off and this error kept showing and the pc can't boot, in a **greenscreen** Windows insider build  run into problem  (page fault in nonpaged area ) failed:volsnap, then automatic repair start up and it failed and give me **bluescreen**  with your pc ran into a problem ,

I've tried to start up repair from windows installation USB but it cant solve the error.

[image]

Comment: That error is caused most of the time either by a faulty driver or hardware problem. Since you say that this happened after a power failure and the error seems to be in the [Volume snapshop service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy) that looks like a hard disk problem. Had you tried starting in [safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode) and perform an error check on the disk?

Comment: update to finale, you use an Insider Build and got a green screen of death instead a blue one. maybe with 16299.15 it is fixed

Comment: This is a known problem with Insider build 17017. Sadly, I am having this problem and don't have a good copy of volsnap.sys to restore. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED BY COPING THE VOLSNAP FROM **C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\System32\drivers**
to  **C:\Windows\System32\drivers** and everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

copyying from old windows folder. Did not works for me.  Tried to copy from a Ubuntu OS to go to the Windows disk, did not work either (files I/O errors)

What did work was copying the volsnap.sys driver from a Bootable Windows 10 USB Fall creator edition stick. Used Rufus to create the bootable stick .

You boot the USB stick, select repair my computer, select command prompt. Delete or rename the C:\windows\System32\driver\volsnap.sys file and copy one from X:\Windows\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\volsnap.sys

Answer (score 0):

Well, this error is mostly faced by every windows user.

But you don't know how to fix this problem?

Don't worry I am here to help you to fix your trouble.

So before we start I want to share some information about this error. This error is a BSOD(blue screen of death) error which usually comes when your memory stopped working but there are many reasons for this error given below:-

1. Suspicious and corrupted antivirus and NTFS.
2. Faulty hardware.
3. Windows PC is not able to find the data that should be in the nonpaged area.

These are the reasons for its occurrence. Now let’s fix this error.

Sol #1: Use [CHKDSK](https://yourwindowshelper.com/page-fault-in-nonpaged-area-windows-10/) command in command prompt, to do it follow the instruction given below:-

1. type in the search bar **Command prompt** and open it as **Administrator**.
2. Type in the following command **chkdsk C: /f /r /x** and hit the **Enter** button on your keyboard.
3. Wait for the process until it's completed and then check the issue is if resolved.

Sol#2: Disable Third-party antivirus

Sol#3: Use windows diagnostic memory tool

Sol#4: Use Troubleshooter.